# Select Date from Time-stamp php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return a timestamp column from mysql DB to include a date only, using php but get the following error:

> Strict Standards: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Moscow' for '3.0/no DST' instead in C:\AppServ\www\website\cPanel\UsersControl.php

You can find my code below.

```
<?
echo date('F/j/Y', strtotime($row['CreatedOn']) ); }}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what PHP tells you, set the timezone with the

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Vancouver");
```

function.
I live near Vancouver so I set mine there, you can check out the list of available timezones [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), in the php manual.

You can also set it in php.ini under date.timezone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DATE_FORMAT() function in mysql query to convert timestamp in specific time. For more details check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)